# Difference between DSF (disulfiram) and DSF-Cu

Tags: nomenclature

I though tetrathiomolybdate (TM) and disulfiram (DSF) were forms of **copper** chelators, so I don’t understand the difference between TM/TM-Cu and DSF/DSF-Cu in the below graph. Are they chemically different?

[image]

---

Chen D, Cui QC, Yang H, Dou QP (2006) Disulfiram, a clinically used anti-alcoholism drug and copper-binding agent, induces apoptotic cell death in breast cancer cultures and xenografts via inhibition of the proteasome activity. Cancer Res 66(21):10425–10433. https://doi.org/10.1158/0008-5472.CAN-06-2126

Comment: Welcome to [Chemistry.se]! I'm afraid, but this question is missing all context. It appears to be taken out of a publication; please cite it. I guess this publication should also explain the graphic, so I'm not sure how this site could be more helpful.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン the publication does explain that DSF-Cu is DSF laced with copper. But that’s all… I’m not sure why more context is needed as I know what DSF-Cu stands for. I’m asking about the chemical/relational differences between these compounds (DSF/DSF-Cu) and established chemical nomenclature. If you do not know the answer, that’s fine. I will wait for someone that can.

Comment: Context is always helpful. If you quote a passage of a text or an image you must also cite it. This is a standard scientific practice. I'm afraid that this is very likely not standard notation, but rather an abbreviation used in this publication. This is definitely not nomenclature though. || I'd like to recommend taking the [tour] to learn more about how this site works.

Comment: I’ve updated it. Then why is this notation practically used in most publications on pubmed/WoS. I’ll exemplify this one?: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/DSF-and-DSF-Cu-inhibited-myeloma-cell-viability-in-a-dose-dependent-and-time-dependent_fig1_339709780

Comment: It is right there: The DSF-copper complex inhibits the chymotrypsin-like activity of purified 20S proteasome and 26S proteasome in breast cancer cells. It has been shown that DSF is able to bind copper (31, 32). Indeed, when a solution of DSF was mixed with a solution of CuCl2 at 1:1 ratio, dramatic color change was observed, from light blue to dark green (data not shown). This indicates that a chemical reaction has occurred that involves formation of a DSF-copper complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are all chemically different compounds—the paper is investigating whether or not a complex of disulfiram on copper has proteasome inhibiting properties. They test this by performing an MTT assay on breast cancer cells, and this data compares all of the groups they constructed for their experiment. The data is—in my opinion—poorly presented, so it makes it unclear what is going on. Let's dissect the groups they are testing:

[image: left part of plot highlighted]

In this plot, they have breast cancer cells for the assay tested against controls of the pure compounds investigated in the study. The cell line was cultured *separately* in presence of: DMSO (DM), copper (Cu) alone, disulfiram (DSF) alone, and tetrathiomolybdate (TM) alone. The figure represents the concentration in $\mu$M that the experiment used, and there is one concentration per compound.

[image: the middle of the plot]

This portion of the plot displays data from the MTT assay for the exact same experiment, but if the DSF is chelating on copper. They ran the individual DSF and Cu separately to ensure that this complex was the one performing proteasome inhibition and not one of its constituents. They tested three different concentrations, so there are three columns for this space. This chemical is chemically different than both DSF and Cu alone.

[image: the right portion of the plot]

This portion of the plot acts as another control for the experiment. The authors want to show that it is the DSF-Cu complex that is doing the inhibition and that this does not generalize to just any copper complex they use. They chelated the copper with TM instead of DSF for the MTT assay to see if this would result in any proteasome inhibition. They tested two concentrations, so there are two columns. The information meant to be derived from this plot is that when DSF coordinates to copper, it has a unique ability to inhibit proteasomes that you don't find with its component parts alone or with similar cancer-relevant chelates.

Comment: I really don't think the data in the paper is presented poorly. If you take your time reading the paper then it is quite sufficiently explained what everything is. Apart from this, there is one sentence exactly explaining what DSF-Cu appears to be, at least to the extend necessary to understand the paper. I honestly think that the question itself is not a good fit for this site and explaining these obvious things is noise in my opinion.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I mean, I disagree with you about what is a good fit for this site—I appreciate questions that are well-articulated and come from thoughtful people, but the purpose of this site is to provide insight about questions in chemistry and this fits the bill. In the sociological research regarding education, it's a well-known problem that teachers often overestimate just how "obvious" some material is, and thus I don't think people with such know-how are fair arbiters of what is obvious. The plot is OK—sufficient for a trained eye, but excellent data presentation is much more elegant imo

Comment: I appreciate you telling me about your opinion; I guess we really do view this site from different angles. However, this is not the place to dig deeper into this discussion, but I invite you to participate in these discussions on [meta]. I believe I have asked especially about this in the last year; it should be easy enough to find. Anyway, my opinion on the question is not an opinion on your answer, which I think explains the graphic well. I may be a bit late, but anyway: Welcome to [chemistry.se]!